# HP ADU report information. Where is it stored?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, windows

I'm working on something but I'm a bit stuck. If I could figure out where certain information that ADU looks at is stored on Windows Server (2003 & 2008), I'd be in great shape. I primarily want to be able to find the Chassis Serial Number without actually launching ADU. I'm trying to write a batch file that pulls information from a remote computer. Does anyone know where I can find that information other than in the ADU page or within the .zip folder created by running ADU?

I've tried searching on Google, I've done a Windows search for the serial number of one of the servers from within the server, and I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is sounds a bit off... so I'm going to make some assumptions about what you're trying to do.

It seems like you're interested in obtaining the serial number of an HP ProLiant server programmatically.

You ask about chassis information and the Array Diagnostics Utility (ADU). The Array Diagnostics Utility output is not where you want to look for this information. It's really for... diagnosing Smart Array RAID controller issues. It does provide server serial number, as well as disk, controller and cache serials... but you will never need that information.

Ways to accomplish this, assuming you want the server's actual serial number:

- Pull the information from the ILO *web* interface of the server(s). It's right there on the main page.
- Pull the serial via the ILO *ssh* interface. The `show /system1` command will output the serial number appended to the 6-digit product number.
- Use something like [dmidecode](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm).
- Leverage the HP command-line tools; specifically `hpasmcli`... Oh, but that may be Linux-only.
- For Windows, use WMI - `wmic /node:SERVERNAME bios get serialnumber`

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do. I started messing around with wmic and that seems to be exactly what I want. I've never used that before, but it looks like it can gather lots of information, could be fun.
Also, the reason I mentioned ADU is because I'm actually gathering the ADU report. The main purpose of this script is to get the report and necessary information from the server without needing to log into it. 

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, use WMI:

```
wmic /node:SERVERNAME bios get serialnumber
```

For Linux, use dmidecode:

```
dmidecode  -t system | grep Serial
```